# Instant search engine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search-engine, partial

I am trying to create an instant search engine in rails.
My searchable model is `tournament`
I added the `gem 'pg_search'`to my gemfile
In my tournament model I have :

`class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search,
  :against => [:name, :address, :city, :club_organisateur, :starts_on, :ends_on, :postcode],
  :using => {:tsearch => {:prefix => true} }`

The search takes place on my `Tournament#index` view, so in my tournaments controller I have :

```
  def index
    @tournaments = policy_scope(Tournament)
    if @tournaments.blank? && current_user.judge?
      render 'pages/partials/_no_tournaments_judge'
    elsif @tournaments.blank?
      render 'pages/partials/_no_tournaments'
    elsif params[:content].blank?
    elsif params[:content]
      @tournaments = @tournaments.search(params[:content])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html{ render :index }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my view (slim) tournament/index I have :

```
div class="container"
  div class="row"
    div class="col-xs-12"
      h1 class="emperor" Recherche de tournois
      = form_tag tournaments_path, method: "get", :remote => true do ||
        div class="form-group"
          = label_tag :content, "recherche"
          = text_field_tag :content, nil, class: "form-control"

        = render "tournaments"
```

Here is the tournaments' partial :

```
div class="row" id="tournament_row"
 - @tournaments.each do |tournament|
    div class="col-md-4"
      div class="panel panel-default"
        div class="panel-heading"
          h2
            = tournament.name
            br
            small = tournament.city.upcase

        div class="panel-body"
          p
            'Du
            strong> = tournament.starts_on.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            'au
            strong = tournament.ends_on.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
          ul
          - tournament.competitions.each do |competition|
            li
              = "#{competition.category} #{competition.genre.text}"
        div class="panel-footer"
          = link_to 'En savoir plus', tournament_path(tournament), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

and Here is my index.js.erb file :

```
$('#tournament_row').html("<%= render 'tournaments' %>");
```

When I check my logs everytime I submit the form, params[:content] is sent to my tournament#index action and I can see that
`@tournaments = @tournaments.search(params[:content])` is working.

My problem is that my tournament/index view **is never updating** to display the tournaments contained in @tournaments... It always stay the same. What is the problem ?

Comment: You'd be better using the terminology "live search" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `escape_javascript`

```
$('#tournament_row').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'tournaments') %>");
```

or

```
$('#tournament_row').html('<%=j render 'tournaments' %>')
```